# Linear System with constrained solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

After a model my problem I found a rectangular linear system :
$$Ax=b$$
I can easely solve it with a least square with QR/SVD... But the model include constrains for each solution $x_i$, the $\vec{x}$ have n elements. ($1\leqslant i\leqslant n$)

For each $x_i$ I have a min and max:
$$
x_i \geqslant min_i
$$
$$
x_i \leqslant max_i
$$
And exist some couple constraint with $(i,j)$ as:
$$
(i,j) \in \left (\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}} \right )^2 | i \neq j
$$
$i$ and $j$ is on $\mathbb{Z}$ and is included on $[1,n]$

I have 2 others kinds of constraints $L^p_{ij}$ and $E^q_{ij}$ on "99.9%" of my cases :
$$
L^p_{ij} = L^p_{ji}
$$
$$
E^q_{ij} = E^q_{ji}
$$
I have N ($1 \leqslant p \leqslant N$) contrains L and K ($1 \leqslant q \leqslant K$) constains E.

$$
L^p_{ij} : x_i + x_j = 1 \space \mathbf{or} \space 0
$$
$$E^p_{ij} : x_i > 0 \Rightarrow x_j = 0$$
I can rewrite $E^q_{ij}$ like :
$$
\begin{matrix}
x_i+x_j=\max(x_i,x_j) \Rightarrow \\
x_i + x_j = \frac{1}{2}\left(x_i + x_j + \left | x_i - x_j  \right |\right) \Rightarrow \\
x_i + x_j = \frac{1}{2}\left (x_i + x_j + \sqrt{ (x_i - x_j)^2  }\right )
\end{matrix}
$$

I search a way to minimize $\|Ax=b\|$ with my $min_i$, $max_i$, $L^p_{ij}$, $E^q_{ij}$.
All $x_i$ have one $min_i$ and $max_i$, but for $L^p_{ij}$ and $E^q_{ij}$ I have no control on number or "topology" constrains.

As you see I have an $\mathbf{or}$ on $L^p_{ij}$ and the derivation of $E^q_{ij}$ is not continue so I can't simply use the Lagrange Multiplier.

Any comment or solutions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Ax = b$ with bounds on $x$ is dealt with in linear programming.  Your $L$ and $E$ constraints will take you into mixed integer linear programming.

Comment: I'm not a specialist of "Mixed Integer Linear Programming" but this method was not developped to constrain the solution as Interger ? In $\mathbb{Z}$.

I forget to specify something, in major part of my cases $min_i = 0$ and $max_i = 1$

So my $x_i$ is not integer.

Thanks

Comment: Your $x_i$ are not integer, but you'd have additional variables that are integer.  That's why it's "mixed".  For example,  $L^p_{ij}$ would be handled with an additional binary variable $u_{ij}$ (i.e. its allowed values are $0$ and $1$), with constraint $x_i + x_j = u_{ij}$.  For $E^p_{ij}$ you'd have binary variables $u_i$ and $u_j$, with constraints $max_i u_i \ge x_i$, $max_j u_j \ge x_j$, $u_i + u_j \le 1$.

Comment: I have no link for $L^p_{ij}$ and $E^q_{ij}$.
For that I'm not sur to understand the second part for $E^p_{ij}$ :
$$
max_i u_i \geqslant x_i ?
$$
$$
max_j u_j \geqslant x_j ?
$$
$$
u_i+u_j\leqslant 1
$$
$max_i u_i$ it is a multiplication ?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's multiplication.  The point is that $\max_i u_i \ge x_i$ means that when $x_i > 0$, $u_i$ can't be $0$ (so it must be $1$), while $u_i = 1$ is always allowed.  $u_i + u_j \le 1$ means you can't have both $u_i = 1$ and $u_j = 1$.

Comment: I see !
Thanks you.
I will find a C++ implementation for a MIP solver.